# composer not install in windows 7

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

I already uncommented in php.ini:

```
[PHP]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
 ; About php.ini ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
```

Variables of the system set ok.

PHP version 5.4.16:

```
  C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe
```

Add to System path variable:

```
  C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
```

But, recive this error:

```
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:

The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are
impossible. If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
```

I'm using:

- windows 7
- Wamp
- php 5.1.16
- apache 2.4.4

How solve this problem, please help me.

Comment: Did you edit the correct .ini?

Comment: Important: open and edit the `php.ini` *as admin*.

Comment: make sure you are editing xampp/php/php.ini

Answer (score 23):

1. Open php.ini located in your "php" folder for example in xampp the file is in XYZ:\xampp\php\
2. Find `"extension=php_openssl.dll"`
3. `";extension=php_openssl.dll"` - remove `";"`
4. Restart your xampp (or whatever u use), extension should be loaded after that.
5. Try agien to install composer.

Comment: I exit the wamp and reopen it, it takes effect after.

Comment: Worked for EasyPHP and I didn't even have to restart anything manually. Thanks.

Comment: I also had to uncomment ; extension_dir = "ext" for the installation to work.

Answer (score 7):

ensure you are editing the php.ini locate on same place where is located php.exe, i was the same problem and wamp say the openssl is actived but Composer-Setup.exe used the php.ini in php directory/ext/ and wamp used C:\System...\php.ini,

Regards,

Comment: For me, WAMP used phpForApache.ini while Composer looked at php.ini

Answer (score 7):

I have battled this several times. And this is the best solution I have found.

As mentioned, you need to ensure that `extension=php_openssl.dll` is enabled but doing just that sometimes may not resolve the error.

You should check that you have PHP on your path variable then see what INI file is loaded by typing `php --ini` in the console it should give you something like:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\WINDOWS\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Make sure you are enabling the settings in the correct ini file. If you dont have an ini file loaded put an ini file from the php directory into `c:\windows`.

**Also important**
I find it helps to change the `extension_dir` flag to an absolute path from relative to makesure the system can find `php_opensll.dll`.

To do this uncomment the line starting `extension_dir` and change it to match from the drive root.

Example: `C:\php\ext` instead of `ext/`

Comment: The two modifications in the php.ini file is what fixed the issue for me.  I have a standalone php installation, not using wamp, xamp.

Answer (score 4):

For MAMP users, this is what worked for me.

If your php.ini is located under a \MAMP\conf\

1. copy the php.ini into a\MAMP\bin\php\php[your PHP version number]\
2. Restart MAMP and the command-line window
3. Go to a directory under a command-line window where you want to install composer
4. run from a command line:
   php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php

NOTE: it is http not https !

END

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was doing my head in. phpinfo was showing openssl as installed/enabled, and php was accessible from command line. Could not see what was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

**I figured it out and successfully installed Composer in My windows 10 PC.**

> I am sharing two solutions here.

**There are some steps you have to follow in order to solve your problem.**

**1st solution.**

1. Find and Open `php.ini` located in your "php" folder In my case it is in xampp the file is in `c:\xampp\php\`
2. Find `"extension=php_openssl.dll"`
3. `";extension=php_openssl.dll"`  **uncomment by removing the semicolon** `";"`
4. Restart your xampp , now extension should be loaded after that.
5. Try again now you are able to install composer.

**2nd solution(If the above solution not work for you then go with below solution . )**

**This works in my case**

1. Find and Open `php.ini` located in your "php" folder In my case it is in xampp the file is in `c:\xampp\php\`
2. Open SHELL from Xampp start panel by clicking on shell button.
3. Write `php` in shell and hit enter
4. If you get some waring message in your shell something like below .
   [image]
5. Then you have to fix these waring message by commenting all these extension in your `php.ini` file.(Actually cause of these warning messages are because more than one time these extensions are enabled but you can **un-comment** it in `php.ini` file for solving the issue).

   **For Example which is in my case.**

   a). You can see in above image there is warning message for curl.

   ```
   Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 .
   ```

   b) To fix this find `php_curl.dll` file in your `php.ini` file and **comment that extension by adding semicolon** `";"` in front of that extension like this `;extension=php_curl.dll`

### Follow above steps if you have more than one warning for each extension untill you are not getting any warning message in your shell.

6. Restart your xampp , now extension should be loaded after that.
7. Try again now you are able to install composer.

**Hope I can solve your issue .**

**That's all folks . Happy coding !!! (amitamie.com) :-) ;-)**

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved after turn off windows firewall.

installation complete!

Answer (score 1):

I nearly wrapped my head off trying to install composer on my **windows 7 machine**.

I was trying to install composer through the composer installer from getcomposer.org.

After the common openssl extension enabling (As above answers describing).

The installer has finished the installation successfully. But calling **composer on the command line**, wasnt 
possible. It was telling me **composer / application** not found, check for typos etc...

Cant getting it running, I looked at the manually install guide and noticed something weird.

The doc said: "Close your current terminal. Test usage with a new terminal:"

**I closed my terminal window. Opened a new one and IT WORKED!!!**

I had a terminal window open during the composer installation. After that I was trying to call composer via the command line in this terminal. This didnt work.

So why did it not work?
The composer installer downloads the composer.phar file and sets a environment path to it. The terminal only gets the environment PATHS, when it gets started. So of course the path wasnt set for the terminal.

**Solution:**

If you have a terminal open before the installation just close it and open a new terminal window to get composer ready to use!!!

I hope I can save someone a couple hours of living time.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this guide:

http://abuango.net/2014/08/16/how-to-install-composer-on-windows-with-xampp/

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find a `php.ini` in `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\` (the configuration file of PHP).
2. Remove `;` in lines `;extension=php_openssl.dll` and `;extension_dir = "ext"`. PHP will know that you are using a php_openssl extension and extension_dir is the location of extensions (you can see it in the comment above php_openssl).
3. Run the Windows command prompt with administrator permissions.
4. Execute the following command: `mklink C:\Windows\php.ini C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.ini`

Composer search `php.ini` in `C:\Windows\php.ini` and you have your PHP in WAMP.  With `mklink` command you create a link `php.ini` that aim to your WAMP's `php.ini`.

Comment: Thanks this worked a treat for php 5.6 downloaded and unzipped from the PHP site.

Comment: Glad to know it, enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue but i fixed that,

if you are using wamp

goto your selected php version directory and then you need to edit that directory php.ini file

replace this line `;extension=php_openssl.dll to extension=php_openssl.dll` and save and then restart then it will be working :)

Answer (score 0):

Beside all of the above If php/xampp is not installed in c drive this problem occurred (what happened with me).

In that case please follow this link : 
http://abuango.net/2014/08/16/how-to-install-composer-on-windows-with-xampp/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in windows 7 PC with xampp.

> Cannot open '\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini' for reading in Unknown on line 0

I just change the value of 'browscap' in php.ini file. Use full path instead of absolute path.

In my case Xampp was in E drive so I have changed
browscap="\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
to
browscap="E:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"

And it works for me!