# SSL error during installing composer on windows

Tags: php, ssl, laravel, composer-php

When I tried to install composer on windows I received this error:

```
"Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:
The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers
are impossible. If possible you should enable it or recompile php 
with --with-openssl"
```

Anybody knows how I can resolve this kind of error ?

Also you should know I enabled ssl on apache server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [composer not install in windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763452/composer-not-install-in-windows-7)

Comment: It could be possible your php is using another php.ini when used from the CLI.

Comment: Thank you Dennis, you were right, I am using WAMP and it uses another php.ini that is deferent from one composer uses !!!

Answer (score 2):

Try `php -m` in your CLI to check if openssl is listed. Then check your php.ini location with `php --ini`

You may be modifying the wrong php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is that following lines should also be enabled.

> include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
>
> extension_dir = "./"
>
> extension_dir = "ext"

Also had the same problem which was solved.

Happy Composing :) :) :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 0):

**Enable openssl from all php.ini**
`;extension=php_openssl.dll =>
 extension=php_openssl.dll`

if you are using wamp then don'nt forget to **restart all services**  after change in php.ini file

Answer (score -1):

I have windows 10 with xampp 3.0.12 (php5.4). I was not able to install composer. I tried below steps it worked for me.

1. download installer script from https://getcomposer.org/installer
2. save it in a file called as composer-setup.php
3. open composer-setup.php in vscode or subline code editor.
4. replace all https to http and save file.
5. execute below 3 steps in command prompt.

   php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'a5c698ffe4b8e849a443b120cd5ba38043260d5c4023dbf93e1558871f1f07f58274fc6f4c93bcfd858c6bd0775cd8d1') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"

   php composer-setup.php

   php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
6. viola! successfully installed composer, you can run: php composer.phar.

Thanks

Comment: not working, it says "Installer corrupt"

Answer (score -1):

Just use -
`--disable-tls`

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '906a84df04cea2aa72f40b5f787e49f22d4c2f19492ac310e8cba5b96ac8b64115ac402c8cd292b8a03482574915d1a8') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php --disable-tls
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Comment: Warning: copy(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in Command line code on line 1

Warning: copy(): Failed to enable crypto in Command line code on line 1

Warning: copy(https://getcomposer.org/installer): Failed to open stream: operation failed in Command line code on line 1