# Installing Composer - Internal Error

Tags: php, composer-php

I have trouble installing `Composer`. After I select the `php.exe` path in the wizard and next thing it shows is the below error description.

> The PHP exe file you specified did not execute correctly: 
>   D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe Running it from the command line
>   might highlight the problem. Internal Error [ERR_INVALID], exit code 1

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command line, as the message says? Maybe PHP is missing from that location.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess this is a problem which had been asked here .

[composer not install in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763452/composer-not-install-in-windows-7/42577587#42577587)

**I figured it out and successfully installed Composer in My windows 10 PC.**

> I am sharing two solutions here.

**There are some steps you have to follow in order to solve your problem.**

**1st solution.**

1. Find and Open `php.ini` located in your "php" folder In my case it is in xampp the file is in `c:\xampp\php\`
2. Find `"extension=php_openssl.dll"`
3. `";extension=php_openssl.dll"`  **uncomment by removing the semicolon** `";"`
4. Restart your xampp , now extension should be loaded after that.
5. Try again now you are able to install composer.

**2nd solution(If the above solution didn't work for you then go with one below. )**

**This works in my case**

1. Find and Open `php.ini` located in your "php" folder In my case it is in xampp the file is in `c:\xampp\php\`
2. Open SHELL from Xampp start panel by clicking on shell button.
3. Write `php` in shell and hit enter
4. If you get some warning message in your shell that looks like the image below:
   [image]
5. Then you have to fix these warning message by commenting all these extension in your `php.ini` file.(Actually cause of these warning messages are because more than one time these extensions are enabled but you can **un-comment** it in `php.ini` file to solve the issue).

   **For Example which is in my case.**

   a). You can see in above image there is warning message for curl.

   ```
   Module 'curl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 .
   ```

   b) To fix this find `php_curl.dll` file in your `php.ini` file and **comment that extension by adding semicolon** `";"` in front of that extension like this `;extension=php_curl.dll`

### Follow above steps if you have more than one warning for each extension until you are not getting any warning message in your shell.

6. Restart your xampp , now extension should be loaded after that.
7. Try again now you are able to install composer.

**Hope I can solve your issue .**

**That's all folks . Happy coding !!! (amitamie.com) :-) ;-)**

Comment: @jassi @ you're welcome !
Give a thumbs up for this ans ;-)  !
Thanks and happy Coding !

Comment: The second solution works for me as well. You have to make sure that all DLLs are loaded properly. In my case the imagick dll is missing so I have to comment by adding semicolon (;) then the composer was successfully installed.

Answer (score 6):

There are some steps you might want to follow in order to solve your problem

1. You can try to change `extension_dir` in `xampp\php\php.ini` to full direction
   like :

   ```
   extension_dir = "E:\xampp\php\ext"
   ```
2. Install it manually   [Is there any way to install Composer globally on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059397/is-there-any-way-to-install-composer-globally-on-windows)
   or you can do it by open XAMPP Shell and write this

   ```
   php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
   ```
3. Just install it in `C:\` partition, I think it will work .

I think the problem its in the Windows8 and above that not give Full permission to use `CMD` .

Comment: only putting the full path for extension_dir  and browscap worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me..,

1. Open xampp>apache>PHP(php.ini)
2. Search for openssl
3. Comment on extension=openssl by adding ; at the beggining

Comment: This worked for me. someone had suggested to uncomment it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no two ways about it. Just go to PHP.ini and comment the mention errors you have on your cmd or shell after typing PHP in it.simple as that problem solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I was running with XDebug, and it was stopping on a breakpoint in my IDE. So, actually, it was working fine! I just needed to remove XDebug for a while from php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because some dll file which is specified in the php.ini is missing. So do the following steps to fix it.

1. Open command prompt and type **php** and hit enter.
2. It will try to execute php and will throw warnings and errors. For example in my case it was like below:
   [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84rdP.png)
3. Now, based on the error, go ahead and comment the extension (listed in the above command) in php.ini file. For example in my case I commented 
   *extension=php_mysql.dll*
   to  ;extension=php_mysql.dll
4. Now try to install the composer again, it should work.

**Note:** If not repeat the process again, may be there are more then one extensions in php.ini are creating the problem in your case, but at cmd, php might give only one error at once.

**Note:** Once you have installed composer you can go ahead and uncomment all the line which you had commented.

Answer (score 0):

There's following step you have to made.

1. Go to C://xampp/php
2. open php.ini and search for "openssl" (Two search may Found!)

;extension=php_openssl.dll

add semi-colon in first and retry again to install composer

Comment: unlike this answer ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362155/308578 this linked article said remove semicolon and solve my problem . so i cant install with composer.setup.exe but help with xampp shell with the command line in this article https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362155/308578

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

1. Go to `Drive_name://xampp/php`
2. Open php.ini and search for "msql.so" and "msql.dll"
3. Change `extension=msql.dll` to `;extension=msql.dll` and `extension=msql.so` to `;extension=msql.so`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the "Visual C++"

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

1. Go to `path/to/xampp/php` and open `php.ini`
2. Search for `extension=php_mcrypt.dll` and comment that by putting semicolon `(;)`. Like Replace `extension=php_mcrypt.dll` With `;extension=php_mcrypt.dll`
3. Save `php.ini`

   Now Try to install `composer` again and it should work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `xampp\php\php.ini`

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to find `extension=intl` and comment it out using `;`

```
;extension=intl
```

Try and install your composer.exe.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I got this error:
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe

Program Output:
PHP:  syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\xampp\php\php.ini on line 1602,

After trying all the above answers:
I open the php.ini file with a code editor and located line 1602 and I saw

```
error_reporting(1) around the eval().
```

so I commented on it using ;

```
;error_reporting(1) around the eval().
```

and my composer installed successfully.