# Composer will not work with your current settings

Tags: php, composer-php

Like the photo below

[image]

I'm not sure what problem it is.

Is it mean the `HKCU\Software...` get an error?

or I miss the `check.php` file?

I just want to do is add facebook login on my page.

I follow the facebook developers(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted) to do so I need to install this software.

Please help, Thank You all

**P.S** 
I am using wamp server latest version

**OS:** win7

Comment: it may be possible your wamp installation is incorrect, try reinstalling wamp and try it again.

Comment: i have a question, if i delete the wamp, what about the file and the phpmyadmin table? because this wamp have my opencart file.

Comment: Do a backup of your files and a database dump, so you can easily restore them afterwars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913142/installing-composer-internal-error

Comment: @pankitGami I have tried that article solution, but not success

Comment: Try this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/42577668/6628079