# Install Composer Error: Incorrect function

Tags: php, installation, composer-php, wamp

I got this error trying to install composer. I'm using WAMP. Can anyone help?

The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.4.0\php.exe

Reported error: Incorrect function

Comment: This question has been asked before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31913142/installing-composer-internal-error

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of the following options:

- Make sure PHP is added to your environment path

OR

- Install [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2019)