# php 5.6.17 has no php.ini

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer to get laravel working. 
Composer gave me the following error:

> Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
>   Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script
>   again:
>
> The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS
>   transfers are impossible. If possible you should enable it or
>   recompile php with --with-openssl

According to this post I need to uncomment the openssl extension. 
[composer not install in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763452/composer-not-install-in-windows-7)

The problem is I don't have a php.ini file in my php directory. There is a php.ini-development and php.ini-production. Do I just rename one of them to php.ini?

This post is in regards to XAMPP, it says that the php.ini file needs to  be edited and not the php.ini-development or php.ini.production.
[Php.ini production vs development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880749/php-ini-production-vs-development)

I downloaded the non-thread safe php x86 from here
http://windows.php.net/download/

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just copy paste php-development.ini and rename it to php.ini.
php 7.0.3 is already out!

Answer (score 2):

use php.ini-development for your development server. use php.ini-production for your production server. Copy and rename it to php.ini

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: Development: error_reporting = E_ALL, display_errors = On,display_startup_errors = On,track_errors = On

Production: error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT, display_errors = Off,display_startup_errors = Off,track_errors = Off

basically development setting turn on error reporting and display error, so that you will be able to notice any error in your coding and fix it immediately.